# Java code has different FPS on two similar machines

Tags: java, optimization, gpu, nvidia, frame-rate

I have been developing my java game for around 1.5 years now, and it has been running with around 3200 FPS on my PC (Intel I7, GTX 970, 8GB RAM).

However a few days back I tried it on my LAPTOP (Intel I7, GTX 1050TI, 16GB RAM). It's hardware is similar to my PC, however it barely hits 50 FPS. I noticed the GPU usage is 0 when running my game (on the laptop, unsure about PC). This difference seems abnormally big compared to the difference on the 2 machine.

I set the GTX 1050TI as first GPU, it increased the FPS from 30 to 50 on the laptop, still the usage is 0 (MSI Afterburner).

The two `for` loops below alone takes up 10 miliseconds on the laptop, but it runs fine on the PC, so I don't think so it is an optimization problem.

```
    int xStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset() / Tile.TILEWIDTH);
    int xEnd = (int) Math.min(width, (handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()
        + handler.getWidth()) / Tile.TILEWIDTH + 1);
    int yStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset() / Tile.TILEHEIGHT);
    int yEnd = (int) Math.min(height, (handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()
        + handler.getHeight()) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT + 1);


    for(int y = yStart; y < yEnd; y++) {
        for(int x = xStart; x < xEnd; x++) {
            getTile(x, y).render(g, (int) (x * Tile.TILEWIDTH
                - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()),
                (int) (y * Tile.TILEHEIGHT - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()));
        }
    }
```

Looking at the hardware of both the PC and the LAPTOP, the FPS should be similar. Is it the GPU usage, or something else?

--UPDATE:

The GPU is working now! on 60% usage, so
I managed to get the laptop to 400FPS, with OPENGL hardware acceleration
Still, is 3200 FPS - 400 FPS realistic for two machines that are this similar in terms of hardware?

Comment: Are we looking - maybe - at RAM usage?

Did you check system information when running the game?

Do you see any bottleneck related to CPU / HDD / RAM?

Comment: Do you use the same JVM on both machines?

Comment: Interesting question. But I doubt we will find an answer here, it is just too vague and too much information is missing. We could just guess right now, and that is not what SO is about. Good luck anyways.

Comment: @Pitto The processor usage is around 50%, RAM is 40%, integrated GPU is 15% and the GTX 1050TI GPU is 0%

Comment: @Cascader I think so, yes.

Comment: Since Java is pretty much agnostic to the underlying hardware, I'd suggest to verify that java version (`java -version` output) is the same. Also, JVM flags should be the same, although there is a chance that JVM flags are the same but are not respected/supported due to version/vendor incompatibility.

Comment: @Cascader on the laptop the java version is: java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode), but i can't verify on the PC right now. However if the PC is running an older java, it should be the slower one right?

Comment: As a general rule, yes: newer is usually faster. However, even tiny details can make huge difference in JVM code optimization. For example, your laptop runs a Server VM which seems odd for a game. I'd try launch the game with `java -client -jar ...` since JVM automatically switches to server VM (there are rules for that but you can always override with `-client` switch).

Comment: @Cascader I have added -client to Eclipse running configurations, it did not help.

Comment: UPDATE: blocking the integrated gpu increased the fps to 100, yet the PC runs on 3200 FPS, so it's still not close.I have a feeling it has something to do with the gpu

Comment: What are the actual I7 processors on the two machines? Also looking at the specs for the GTX 970, https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-970/specifications, and the GTX 1050TI, https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1050-ti/specifications, there are quite a few significant differences between the two so far as CUDA cores, memory interface width, and memory bandwidth.

Comment: PC has: I7-4770 3.40gHz LAPTOP has: I7-8750H 2.20GHz @RichardChambers

Comment: You keep saying that the two machines, PC and laptop, are similar but they are not. Different GPUs, https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-970-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1050-Ti/2577vs3649 . Differences in the specs on the GPUs look to be significant. See also these articles: https://www.polygon.com/2014/6/5/5761780/frame-rate-resolution-graphics-primer-ps4-xbox-one and  https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/nvidia-frameview-power-and-performance-benchmarking-app-download/ and https://www.avadirect.com/blog/frame-rate-fps-vs-hz-refresh-rate/

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, I do realize they are not the same, im just worried if that performance difference is normal, or the code is wrong.